# Largest rectangle that can be inscribed within a higher degree polynomial not broken up by the y axis?

Tags: calculus, optimization, quartics

So I understand how to solve for the largest rectangle that can be inscribed under a basic quadratic say $9-x^2$ (Using optimization), but I have no clue how to do it for an equation like $2x^4+4x^3+3x+1.$ How would you go about solving something like this? The only way we learned was to divide the graph into two sections $(-x\text{ and }+x).$ These two sides were of equal magnitude, since it was a parabola, so to maximize area you could just do $2x(y)$ and $y$ could be written in terms of $x.$ Taking the derivative of this would give you the max area and then you could solve for dimensions.

However, I have no idea how to do it will something even slightly more complicated, like a quartic function that isn't equally divided by the $y$ axis.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the question: You want to find points $x_0<x_1$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$ and for $x_0 < x < x_1, f(x)<f(x_0)=f(x_1)$ Is this correct?

Comment: In my earlier comment I mean $f(x)=2x^4+4x^3+3x+1.$

Comment: In this case, I don't think there are any inscribed rectangles, if my understanding of "inscribed rectangle" is correct.  In general, you have two independent variables, so the problem will require methods from the calculus of functions of several variables, which I take it you haven't studied yet.

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't be possible just using the two variables. The same principles should apply right? You multiply the base by the width and maximize it. It shouldn't matter whether the function is of a higher degree right? And yes the above statement is what I am trying to find. Thing is, it makes sense that there is one inscribed rectangle that must be the greatest. So there must be a way to find out what it is since we know the curve and what we are solving for. I just don't understand how it would work.

Comment: The problem is finding $x_0, x_1$ where the function takes equal values.  In the example you gave, the function has a global minimum, and is decreasing to the left of it, increasing to the right, so you'd have to pick on point on either side of the critical point, and the top of the rectangle would be above the curve.  What I said about functions of several variables probably isn't correct, now that I think about it more, but that doesn't mean the problem will be easy to solve.